# jqgrid - why after jquery.ajax(type:html) then jqgrid reload event not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jqgrid

:)

I have a problem with jqgrid.

I'm using two pages.

The main page(=call "A") has a one jqgrid.

and it's simple grid.

The second page(=call "B") are call from page "A" via jquery ajax (dataType : "html").

And "B" page has two jqgrid as a inlineHTML.

=========
And now the problem is, after loaded "B" page (no problem in "B" page). 
In "A" page. 
The $grid.trigger("reloadGrid"); is not working.

But if not use jquery.ajax event, then "A" page works.

=========
here is my source.

**[1] page > "A" > call method "B"**

```
$.ajax({
            url: "B.html",
            dataType : "html"           }).done(function(result) {
            $('#div_memberSearchPopup').bPopup({ //                           content:'ajax' //'ajax', 'iframe' or 'image' //                            contentContainer:'.memberSearchPopup_content'
                  zIndex: 2 //                          , modalClose: false
                , positionStyle: 'fixed'
                , follow: [false, false]
                , position: [100, 100]
                , onOpen: function() {
                    $('#div_memberSearchPopup').find(".memberSearchPopup_content").html(result);
                    $('#div_memberSearchPopup').draggable();
                }
            });
      });
```

**[2] page > "B" > reload method "A".trigger("reloadGrid")**

```
$gridElement.jqGrid('clearGridData')
                        .jqGrid('setGridParam', {
                url  : "A.html",
                page       : 1,
                mtype : "get",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType : "json",
                postData   : dataValue,
                loadComplete: function(){
                    if(typeof loadCompleteFunc === 'function') {
                        loadCompleteFunc();
                        }
                    }
            }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Comment: you should include HTML code of both `a.html` and `b.html`. Probably you have some `id` duplicates? What is `$gridElement`? Moreover the options of `setGridParam` contains definitively some errors: you use `dataType : "json"` instead of `datatype : "json"` and `contentType: "application/json"` instead of `{ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json" }`. The value `dataValue` which you use for `postData` could be important too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for read this question.

I resolved my problem.

The problem is included duplicated javascript library.

I are using tile template then in template's has a includes.

So I resolved i my self! Thanks all!!!